# List comprehension - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list-comprehension, typeerror

I am using list comprehension to generate a list of products of two values, and am seeing a TypeError. A simplified example is below.

```
def exp_n(n):
    k = 5
    s = 1
    a = [5*max(x+s-K) for x in range(0,n)]
    print(a)
    
exp_n(10)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

From looking at other posts, it seems like this usually has to do with the iterable defined in the forloop returing a non-iterable. But here, `range(0,n)` is certainly iterable. Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: `x+s-K` is a single number. What do you want with `max(x+s-K)`?

Comment: `max(x+s-K)`: *K* is not defined and `max` expects an iterable not an integer.

Comment: The issue is your usage of `max`, not `range`.

Comment: **facepalm** thank you guys

Comment: Maybe what you really want is `max(x + s - K for x in range(n))`? But then why do you have a list comprehension?

Comment: Just do ```5 * (max(range(n)) + s - k)``` or ```5 * (n - 1 + s - k)```.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the code I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
def exp_n(n):
    k = 5
    s = 1
    a = 5*max([(x+s-k) for x in range(0,n)])
    print(a)
    
exp_n(10)
```